# React Children Only crashing on load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been struggling with this for hours, can't seem to figure out what is wrong.I have tried wrapping everything in divs to make it one component, putting my provider at the top level wrapper around AppRouter, nothing. 
[image]

```
 class AppRouter extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                <Router>
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Navigation brand="visua" loggedIn={SHOW} routes={routes}/> 
                        {[...routes].map((route) => <Route path={route.path} component={route.component}/>)}</React.Fragment>
                </Router>
            </ApolloProvider>
        )

    }

}

export default AppRouter;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppRouter from './router.jsx'

ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter/>, document.getElementById('rootp'));
```

Comment: assuming that you are using react-router-dom, `Router` should only accept one child, you are mapping over your routes and those become direct children of `Router`, wrap them in a `div`

Comment: dont understand they are already wrapped in React.Fragment as a the base component under Router

Comment: Figured it out! was an issue with a ThemeProvider